# How to send response from server after submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, python, json, server, xmlhttprequest

I want to send a result from python server as a response to the client JavaScript.
My JavaScript code is here:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  d = document;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var f = d.createElement('form');
  f.action = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/Get%20Form/';
  f.method = 'post';
  var i = d.createElement('input');
  i.type = 'hidden';
  i.name = 'url';
  i.value = tab.url;
  f.appendChild(i);
  d.body.appendChild(f);
  f.submit();
});
}, false);
```

And also my python server code as follows:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, url_for, request, 
  render_template,jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
user=""@app.route('/Get Form/',methods = ['POST'])
def GetForm():`
  request.method == 'POST'
  url=request.form['url']  
  print url
  data={}
  data['url'] = url 
  data['result'] = 'safe'
  response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type = "application/json")      
  print response
  return

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0', use_reloader=False)
```

Any body help me to send the JSON object response to the client JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FormData()` with the `XMLHttpRequest()` variable `xhr` at code at Question

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/Get%20Form/");
  xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText) // do stuff with response from server
  }
  xhr.onerror = function(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("url", tab.url);
  xhr.send(fd);
```

Comment: I Implemented your answer. But i still getting errors. File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1725, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response and didnt show the response value in console

Comment: What is purpose of backtick `\`` at `def GetForm():\``?

Comment: Actually i am trying to create a chrome extension which access the current tab url and in python server side i am finding the current url is phishing site or not. Now i am able to receive form value to python server. My problem is that i cant send back my result to the javascript client. The GetForm function is just for reading the tab url from the client javascript code. Can u help me to send the result from python to javascript for further execution.??

Comment: @JishnuRamachandran Have minimal experience using python

Comment: Yaa. i have some basic experience. but i can,t achieve in case of an Extension.